# programatically change the color of a highcharts spline series?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i have a spline series. its color is blue. depending on some condition i want to change the color of it to green or red.
how to do that.
i tried the following way but it didn't work

```
var rawChart = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('kpiprojectrawvaluechart')[0];
var upperSeries = rawChart.series[0];
var lowerSeries = rawChart.series[2];

if(status == 'danger'){
  upperSeries.color = 'red';
}
else {
 upperSeries.color = 'green';
}

rawChart.refresh();
```

please help me

Comment: Can you put up a jsFiddle of your code with some sample data. Many ways to skin a cat here so it would be best to see what you are starting with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using:

```
chart.series[0].graph.attr('stroke', 'green');
```

Here is the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/mhardik/BCH9t/